# Max data storage,extent data storage limit

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, size

1.What is the max amount of data that can be stored in Sharepoint 2013?

2.Can we extent the size storage location ?

3.What is the max no of users allowed in sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

1. Max size of content database is 4 TB.
2. Max of user profiles is 2,000,000 per service application

The limites are describeded here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx